# React: URL Profile ID doesn't match (match.params.id)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

So whenever I clicked the View Profile Link

```
 <Link to={`/profile/${_id}`} className="btn btn-primary">
                View Profile
 </Link>
```

It shows in the URL the User ID of the Profile which is Good.

But whenever I Clicked it to Match it with this Button I get an error.

```
const Profile = ({ getProfileById, match }) => {
useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(match.params.id);
}, [getProfileById]);

return <div>test</div>;
```

};

I get on my console

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

this is what is in my app Js.

```
   <Route
         exact
         path="/profile/:id"
         component={Profile}
     />
```

I think it doesn't match with the URL to the button I clicked.

and inside the Redux Devtools it only returns a Profile Error.

Comment: With useEffect the dependency array argument is meant to contain the variables that the effect should monitor for changes in order to determine when to run.  The linter is telling you to pass it `[match.params.id]`.

Comment: how would I do that? in the tutorial that I follow this has the same code but it worked fine with them.

Comment: I always use this comment ( eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps ) and worked fine. but this one is getting really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what's wrong. It's in my API. I am trying to hit the .get in my API

[image]

But inside my API it is indicated the patch. [image]

and I changed it to get. [image]

and it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the linter rule which is producing the warning: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`, is telling you that you have another dependency.  Use this instead:

```
const Profile = ({ getProfileById, match }) => {
useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(match.params.id);
}, [getProfileById, match.params.id]);

return <div>test</div>;
```

The linter doesn't explore your whole app to determine where and how `match` is used. It also couldn't know how you intend to use it in the future, as a result, it asks that you put it in the dependency array along with `getProfileId`.

If you had imported `getProfileId` or placed it outside of the component instead of passing it down as a prop, you could safely remove `getProfileId` from the dependencies.   All of this is to say that figuring out what goes inside the array takes a bit of additional understanding. Dan Abramov wrote a great [blog post](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/) that helped me wrap my head around when and how to use the dependency array.  This [post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/when-to-use-functions-in-hooks-dependency-array/) might be a good place to start, if you find Dan's post a bit too broad since it deals with more generalized concepts of writing resilient components.

Comment: I already did that and in my redux devtools it returns profile null. and with my reducers Profile Error.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the problem is unrelated to the linter warning.  What does `getProfileById` look like?

Comment: Also, you could rule out what you said that you `think it doesn't match with the URL to the button` by examining the prop in your react devtools (or even just console logging the `match.params.id`).

Comment: this is my getProfileById // GET PROFILE BY ID
export const getProfileById = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/profile/user/${userId}`);

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PROFILE,
            payload: res.data,
        });